# TableView cell expansion not happening for single cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am expanding a `tableViewCell`by using the below.However the problem is I am able to expand multiple cells at a time.What I want to do is , if one cell is expanded and any other cell is clicked, the previous one should be unexpanded thus one cell at a time.

Here is how I am expanding.

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


if ([self.expandedCells containsObject:indexPath]) {


    [self.expandedCells removeObject:indexPath];



}else{
    isExpanded=YES;
    [self.expandedCells addObject:indexPath];
    //Populate expanded cell here

 }

 [self.tableView beginUpdates];
 [self.tableView reloadData];
 [self.tableView endUpdates];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it.Just had to check array count before adding anything.

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


  if ([self.expandedCells containsObject:indexPath]) {


  [self.expandedCells removeObject:indexPath];



  }else{
   isExpanded=YES;
   if (self.expandedCells.count>0) {
   [self.expandedCells removeAllObjects];
    }


  [self.expandedCells addObject:indexPath];
  //Populate expanded cell here

}

 [self.tableView beginUpdates];
 [self.tableView reloadData];
 [self.tableView endUpdates];


}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming that self.expandedCells has the array of cells to be expanded. If thats the case, in didSelctRow, remove all objects from the expandedCells array and then add the selected cell. And perform reload.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    [self.expandedCells removeAllObjects];
    isExpanded=YES;
    [self.expandedCells addObject:indexPath];



     [self.tableView beginUpdates];
     [self.tableView reloadData];
     [self.tableView endUpdates];


}
```

Comment: I can still expand multiple cells .But when I click any expanded cell again, all cells are removed.

Comment: And if I move the `isExpanded=YES; [self.expandedCells addObject:indexPath];` inside `if` the cells donot exapnd.